# A way to deploy a MERN app to Azure instead of Heroku

Tags: reactjs, azure, deployment, mern

I was wondering how to deploy my mern app to Azure. I've been googling for days and it got me really frustrated. When I build my app it obviously only builds the client side. How can I upload my whole project to Azure and run the client side as well as the server side of the app?

I'd like to avoid Heroku and directly run my project from Azure.

Are there any tools I can use for the build?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What Azure service would you like to use to deploy your MERN app? Azure WebApp or VM?

Comment: Azure webapp :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make a MERN app work on Azure, you have to configure your app to display your static react build through express.

Edit your express `server.js` and add this:

```
const path = require("path"); // on top

// Serve Static assests if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build")); // change this if your dir structure is different
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Then, add this script line to your express `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "azure": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client && npm run start"
  }
```

Note: Edit this to meet your directory structure.

That's it, now upload your app to Azure and set your express port to `80` in the environment vars in your Azure application settings.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean server.js needs to be in the root? Because I currently have a folder server-side and a folder client-side in the root. And after this I just need to build the client side only and deploy that to the server?

Comment: Better if you keep the server in root. You don't need to manually build the react app, it will do that for you when Azure runs `npm run azure`.

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala can you pls confirm the variable in .env will be NODE_ENV = "PRODUCTION" right ?