# Deploying a MERN Stack application to azure app service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express

I want to deploy my MERN stack application to Azure App Service. Till now whatever tutorials I came across, they all have one git repo with client and server code in the same directory and in server.js file they are doing this:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => { 
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

same approach I found almost everywhere. But in my case I have two different git repos, one for the react application and one for the node-express application. Also in my server.js file have following code:

```
routes.all("*", (_req: any, _res: any, next: any) =>
 next(new APIError(
   `${_req.originalUrl} is not found on this server`,HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND,true
  )
 )
);
```

so am not sure how to deploy my MERN app to azure. Can some one please provide guidance.

I followed following two tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](https://medium.com/@chrisjr06/creating-mern-stack-app-and-hosting-in-microsoft-azure-using-create-react-app-w-continuous-4acef0c87e71)

[Tutorial 2](https://medium.com/@tuna.sogut/how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-azure-via-continuous-integration-a3a551526e26)

Comment: did you get this figured out?

Comment: no @patrickgamer not yet. Am exploring docker and k8s option for it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A way to deploy a MERN app to Azure instead of Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983971/a-way-to-deploy-a-mern-app-to-azure-instead-of-heroku)