# Deploying MERN app into Azure, have been using "localhost" to run locally

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, mern

I am developing a web application using the MERN stack with MongoDB and i am facing issue while deploying the app into Azure Web Services. To this point, I have been able to run the app properly on localhost, but I am not sure why my app is not working in Azure environment.

**Snippet from server.js**

```
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));
app.use(cors());
const URI = "db_URI";

mongoose.connect(URI, { 
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    });
connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('db connected..!');
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build",     
    "index.html"));
 });
 
app.use('/api/userModel', require('./backend/routes/User'));
app.use('/projects', require('./backend/routes/projects'));
const Port = process.env.Port || 2000;
app.set('port', Port)
app.listen(Port,()=>console.log("Server started on port " + Port));
```

**Connection Usage**

`axios.get('http://localhost:2000/projects/' + this.props.match.params.id)`

How must I change this connection to work within Azure?

Comment: I don't really get your question but try this 
axios.get(` http://localhost:${port}/projects/ ` + this.props.match.params.id).  hope its help

Comment: I am using localhost:2000 to run to server code in my local environment. When trying to run this server code in the Azure environment it does not work. What do I need to substitute in place of localhost?

Comment: Instead of ```localhost``` use this instead axios.get(` ${location.host}:${port}/projects/ ` + ...the rest of your code  ____ try console log location.host to find the ip

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to change your connection usage.

Using the `express.static` middleware on the `server.js` allows the server to serve static assets from the specified directory.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require("path"); // on top

// Serve Static assests if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build")); // change this if your dir structure is different
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Please have a look at these:

1. [Creating MERN Stack App and Hosting In Microsoft Azure](https://medium.com/@chrisjr06/creating-mern-stack-app-and-hosting-in-microsoft-azure-using-create-react-app-w-continuous-4acef0c87e71)
2. [How to Deploy a MERN Stack App to Azure via Continuous Integration](https://medium.com/@tuna.sogut/how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-azure-via-continuous-integration-a3a551526e26)
3. [A way to deploy a MERN app to Azure instead of Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983971/a-way-to-deploy-a-mern-app-to-azure-instead-of-heroku)